# Add ellipsis for child divs inside a fixed height parent div

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

I have a parent div of a fixed height, overflow hidden and multiple child divs inside it, how do I show an ellipsis after the visible child divs to convey that there are more divs.

this is my code so far:

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
}

.child {
  margin-right: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    first
  </div>
   <div class="child">
    second
  </div>
   <div class="child">
    third
  </div>
   <div class="child">
    fourth
  </div>
</div>
```

Here as the third and fourth child are hidden I want to show dots after second div

Also, the number of child divs could vary, so I want to show the dots only when the parent div overflows

Comment: .parent:after {content:'...'}

Comment: @mr.void Thank you for your suggestion but :after will show the dots even when the parent div doesn't overflow, say if we have only one child div. The number of child divs are dynamic and could vary

Comment: @NikitaSharma you talk about floating divs, but I don't see any?

Comment: @Salketer sorry, edited the question, the child divs are not floating

Comment: @NikitaSharma this isnt possible as far as im aware in pure css. Without it just being based on the current hardcoded height

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.showLessBtn').hide();
var fixedHeight = 50;

var allParents = $('body').find('.parent');
for(var x = 0; x < allParents.length; x++){
  var allChildsOfThisParent = $(allParents[x]).find('.child');
  var parentHeight = 0;
  var childHeight = 0;
  parentHeight = $(allParents[x]).height();
  for(var y = 0; y < allChildsOfThisParent.length; y++){
    childHeight = childHeight +           $(allChildsOfThisParent[y]).height();
  }
  if(childHeight > parentHeight){
    $(allParents[x]).find('.showMoreBtn').show();
  }else{
    $(allParents[x]).find('.showMoreBtn').hide();
  }
}

$(".showMoreBtn").on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().css({'height':'auto'});
  var parentNewHeight = 0;
  parentNewHeight = $(this).parent().parent().height();
  $(this).parent().find('.showLessBtn').css({'top':parentNewHeight+10});
  
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).parent().find('.showLessBtn').show();
});

$(".showLessBtn").on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().css({'height':fixedHeight});
  $(this).parent().find('.showMoreBtn').show();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}

.showMoreBtn, .showLessBtn{
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 55px;
  height: 10px;
  padding-top:0;
  background: transparent;
}


.child {
    padding: 2px;
}
.child>div{
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <button class="showMoreBtn" type="button">.....</button>
    <button class="showLessBtn" type="button">...</button>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div>
      first
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="child">
    <div>
      second
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="child">
    <div>
      third
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="child">
    <div>
      fourth
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```